# Entity Framework - I want the database to be created on a different SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework

My EF tutorial project works fine on a machine with SQL Server installed, but when I move the project to a machine with no SQL Server installed, the code below fails:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EmployeeDb>());
```

I'd like to get the project working on a machine which has only the SQL Server client not the server. I've experimented with connection strings in `app.config` without success. Help much appreciated.

Comment: there is no dependency to have sql server running on machine,if you wanted to access remote database you need to specify that in your connection config file

Comment: Thanks.   That's what i want to do.  How do i specify the remote database in the config file?  can you point me to a reference?

Answer (score 1):

you have install SQL server in separate machine and configure to connect from other systems and put that machine name(or IP address) in connection string.

[Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

[how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't clear enough in my question.   I have a SQL Server that i want to use in conjunction with the machine where my code runs.  I want to configure my EF project so that it connects to this different server - not local SQL instance.